# d3.js: Align text labels between ticks on the axis

Tags: d3.js, calendar, label, axis-labels

Is there an easy way to align text labels between ticks?

Here is my time axis with labels above the ticks:
[image]

I would like to place these labels like here:
[image]

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I ended up with one of the [Lars Kotthoff's advices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544546/d3-js-align-text-labels-between-ticks-on-the-axis/17544785#17544785).

Every time when I `call(axis)` I also adjust text labels.
Here is simplified code:

```
function renderAxis() {
    axisContainer
        .transition().duration(300)
        .call(axis)                  // draw the standart d3 axis
        .call(adjustTextLabels);     // adjusts text labels on the axis 
}

function adjustTextLabels(selection) {
    selection.selectAll('.major text')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + daysToPixels(1) / 2 + ',0)');
}

// calculate the width of the days in the timeScale
function daysToPixels(days, timeScale) {
    var d1 = new Date();
    timeScale || (timeScale = Global.timeScale);
    return timeScale(d3.time.day.offset(d1, days)) - timeScale(d1);
}
```

**Update**:
BTW, here is a **calendar demo** with I ended up: http://bl.ocks.org/oluckyman/6199145

[image]

Comment: I was able to make this work in a newer D3 version, `d3.time.day` is now `d3.timeDay`

Answer (score 7):

There is no easy (i.e. built-in) way of doing this, but you can still achieve it. There are a few options. The most straightforward one is probably to use the [`tickFormat` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickFormat) to specify a format with a suitable number of spaces in front/after the numbers. This would need to be hand-tuned for each application though.

Alternatively, you could select the label elements after they have been drawn and add a suitable `transform` attribute that shifts them accordingly. Again, this would have to be hand-tuned.

Your third option is to have two different axes, one for the ticks and one for the labels. The idea is that the axis that provides the ticks has no labels and the other one no ticks. You would need to set the tick values appropriately, but at least you wouldn't have to guess the right offset.

Comment: the first one wouldn't help in my case because the axis is zoomable.

Comment: In all of these cases you would have to reset the appropriate parameters after zooming.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider using [D3FC](https://d3fc.io/), which has a drop-in replacement for the D3 axis component that supports this feature.

Here's an example which substitutes the D3 axis `d3.axisBottom`, for the D3FC equivalent `fc.axisBottom`:

```
const axis = fc.axisBottom(linear)
  .tickCenterLabel(true);
```

The `tickCenterLabel` centres the axis labels as requested.

Here's what the axis looks like with `tickCenterLabel = false`:

[image]

And here with the `tickCenterLabel = true`:

[image]

**Full disclosure** - I'm a maintainer and contributor to D3FC

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using `axis.tickSize(major[[,minor],end])` and `.tickSubdivide()`. Your ticks are set to line up with the major ticks, but if you set the height of these ticks to 0, and set some height for minor ticks, and specify that there is one minor tick between each pair of major ticks, you will end up with tick labels between your ticks. Your code would look like this:

```
var myAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .ticks(15)
    .tickSubdivide(1)
    .tickSize(0, 6, 0);
```

Note that you need to explicitly set an end size. If you only provide two numbers, they will be interpreted as `major` and `end` and `minor` will default to 0.

Here's a [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/83Wzg/)

Comment: Nice hack! But because of this hack the data will be shifted and instead of "3" you will get "3.5". See the image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/OmfDN.png

Comment: I would caution against putting a label in a different place than the tick representing that value. As a user, I would assume that a tick between two labels would represent a value between the labels. Having it represent the number on one side of it or the other creates ambiguity. Also, d3 doesn't have a way to do it.

Comment: There is a special case: calendar. In the calendar dates and weekdays are placed between ticks.

Answer (score 1):

I often do this by stacking multiple axes, each with a custom `.tickFormat()`.

If I'm placing labels in between dates, I'll often do something like this:

```
@timeDaysAxisLabels = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(@timescale)
    .orient('bottom')
    .ticks(d3.time.hour.utc, 12)  # I want ticks at noon, easiest to just get them ever 12 hours
    .tickFormat((d) =>
        # only draw labels at noon, between the date boundaries
        if d.getUTCHours() == 12
            # draw the label!
            formatter = d3.time.format.utc('%a %d %b')  # "Mon 12 Apr"
            return formatter(d)
        else
            # not noon, don't draw anything
            return null)
    .tickSize(0)
    .tickPadding(30)
```

I'll also create a separate axis with no labels at all, and a non-zero `.tickSize()` to actually draw ticks, but this block above positions date labels in the center of the "column".

Answer (score 1):

Already a few good replies but just to add one more. Note the use of `text-anchor`.

Same idea: After your call, select the text, reposition.

```
.call(xAxis)                
.selectAll(".tick text")
.style("text-anchor", "start")
.attr("x", axisTextAdjust)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "axis axis-years")
          .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height + 1) + ")")
          .call(xAxis)
        .selectAll("text")

     .attr("x", "-1.8em")
     .attr("y", ".00em")
     .attr("transform", function (d) {
         return "rotate(-90)"});
```