# Axis Range and Domain issue on bar graph using D3

Tags: d3.js, graph, axis

I am implementing a bar graph in which the as per the moment of the slider the vertical values of rows would change. I'm getting issue in adding a particular range on the Y-axis domain and decreasing the thickness of both the Y and X Axis. for Y-axis I want the data to be added via the array "ydata" but only first two value gets reflected in this case. The value should be "0-9", "20-29", "40-49", "60-69", "80-89" and "100+" My code is feature on this link:

https://digitalxlabs.com/d3-charts/retirement-transition-graph.php

Username: DXLdemo
Password: View@098#

Also, here is my code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<style>
div#slider{
    width: 500px;
    margin-left: 20%;
    height:5px;
    margin-top: 4%; 
    }
svg {
    margin-left:8%; 
    }
.x-class{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:20px;
    color::blue;    
    }
.y-axis{
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
        line-height:20px;
    color::grey;    
    }
    .year-bar{ width:120%; float:left; margin-left:-15px; margin-top:20px}
.years{ width:auto; float:left; margin-right:68px; font-size:13px}
.age-bar{
    z-index:1;
    width:20%; 
    float:left;
    left:20%;
    margin-top:35px;
    }
.age{
    width:auto;
    float:left;
    margin-right:4px;
    font-size:15px;
    }
</style>

<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>

    <script data-require="jquery@2.1.4" data-semver="2.1.4" src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="jqueryui@1.10.0" data-semver="1.10.0" rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.css" />
    <script data-require="jqueryui@1.10.0" data-semver="1.10.0" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="slider">
    <div class="year-bar">
<span class="years">2000</span>
<span class="years">2010</span>
<span class="years">2020</span>
<span class="years">2030</span>
<span class="years">2040</span>
<span class="years">2050</span>
</div>


    </div>
<!--/*<div class="age-bar">
<span class="age">100+</span><br/>
<span class="age">80-89</span><br/>
<span class="age">60-69</span><br/>
<span class="age">40-49</span><br/>
<span class="age">20-29</span><br/>
<span class="age">0-9</span><br/>*/-->

    <script>
    $(function() {

var extensionMethods = {

            pips: function( settings ) {

                options = {

                    first:  "number",   // "pip" , false
                    last:   "number",   // "pip" , false
                    rest:   "pip"       // "number" , false

                };

                $.extend( options, settings );

                // get rid of all pips that might already exist.
                this.element.addClass('ui-slider-pips').find( '.ui-slider-pip' ).remove();

                // we need teh amount of pips to create.
                var pips = this.options.max - this.options.min;                 

                    // for every stop in the slider, we create a pip.
                    for( i=0; i<=pips; i++ ) {

                        // hold a span element for the pip
                        var s = $('<span class="ui-slider-pip"><span class="ui-slider-line"></span><span class="ui-slider-number">'+i+'</span></span>');

                        // add a class so css can handle the display
                        // we'll hide numbers by default in CSS, and show them if set.
                        // we'll also use CSS to hide the pip altogether.
                        if( 0 == i ) {
                            s.addClass('ui-slider-pip-first');
                            if( "number" == options.first ) { s.addClass('ui-slider-pip-number'); }
                            if( false == options.first ) { s.addClass('ui-slider-pip-hide'); }
                        } else if ( pips == i ) {
                            s.addClass('ui-slider-pip-last');
                            if( "number" == options.last ) { s.addClass('ui-slider-pip-number'); }
                            if( false == options.last ) { s.addClass('ui-slider-pip-hide'); }
                        } else {
                            if( "number" == options.rest ) { s.addClass('ui-slider-pip-number'); }
                            if( false == options.rest ) { s.addClass('ui-slider-pip-hide'); }
                        }


                        // if it's a horizontal slider we'll set the left offset,
                        // and the top if it's vertical.
                        if( this.options.orientation == "horizontal" ) 
                            s.css({ left: '' + (100/pips)*i + '%'  });
                        else
                            s.css({ top: '' + (100/pips)*i + '%'  });


                        // append the span to the slider.
                        this.element.append( s );

                    }

            }


        };

        $.extend(true, $['ui']['slider'].prototype, extensionMethods);


        $("#slider").slider({
            min: 0,
            max: 500,
            step: 100,


            // on slide adjust width of all rects
            slide: function(event, ui) {

                svg.selectAll("rect")
                        .attr("width", function (d) {


                if(ui.value >=0 && ui.value <= 15){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid1);
                            }

            else if(ui.value >=15 && ui.value <= 30){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid2);
                            }

            else if(ui.value >=30 && ui.value <= 45){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid3);
                            }

            else if(ui.value >=45 && ui.value <= 60){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid4);
                            }

            else if(ui.value >=60 && ui.value <= 75){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid5);
                            }

            else if(ui.value >=75 && ui.value <= 90){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid6);
                            }       
            else if(ui.value >=90 && ui.value <= 110){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid7);
                            }

            else if(ui.value >=110 && ui.value <= 130){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid8);
                            }

            else if(ui.value >=130 && ui.value <= 150){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid9);
                            }

            else if(ui.value >=150 && ui.value <= 165){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid10);
                            }

            else if(ui.value >=165 && ui.value <= 190){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid11);
                            }

            else if(ui.value >=190 && ui.value <= 205){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid12);
                            }                               
            else if(ui.value >=205 && ui.value <= 220){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid13);
                            }

            else if(ui.value >=220 && ui.value <= 240){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid14);
                            }

            else if(ui.value >=240 && ui.value <= 260){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid15);
                            }

            else if(ui.value >=260 && ui.value <= 280){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid16);
                            }

            else if(ui.value >=280 && ui.value <= 300){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid17);
                            }

            else if(ui.value >=300 && ui.value <= 315){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid18);
                            }       
            else if(ui.value >=315 && ui.value <= 330){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid19);
                            }

            else if(ui.value >=330 && ui.value <= 350){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid20);
                            }

            else if(ui.value >=350 && ui.value <= 375){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid21);
                            }

            else if(ui.value >=375 && ui.value <= 390){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid22);
                            }

            else if(ui.value >=390 && ui.value <= 405){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid23);
                            }

            else if(ui.value >=405 && ui.value <= 420){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid24);
                            }   

            else if(ui.value >=420 && ui.value <= 435){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid25);
                            }

            else if(ui.value >=435 && ui.value <= 450){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid26);
                            }

            else if(ui.value >=450 && ui.value <= 465){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid27);
                            }

            else if(ui.value >=465 && ui.value <= 480){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid28);
                            }

            else if(ui.value >=480 && ui.value <= 495){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid29);
                            }

            else if(ui.value >=495 && ui.value <= 510){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid30);
                            }       
            else if(ui.value >=510 && ui.value <= 525){
                            return (d.rate * d.mid31);
                            }



                    /*else{
                            return Math.min(ui.value*d.rate, d.max);}*/
                        })
            }
        });

        // create svg
        var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", 740)
                .attr("height", 800);

        /**/         

        // add 4 rects
        var data = [


            { row:1, rate:0.3, mid1:0, mid2:0, mid3:0, mid4:0, mid5:0, mid6:0, mid7:0, mid8:0, mid9:0, mid10:0, mid11:0, mid12:0, mid13:0, mid14:0, mid15:0, mid16:0, mid17:0, mid18:0, mid19:0, mid20:0, mid21:0, mid22:0, mid23:0, mid24:0, mid25:0, mid26:0, mid27:10, mid28:10, mid29:20, mid30:25, mid31:25},

            { row:2, rate:0.4, mid1:80, mid2:80, mid3:85, mid4:90, mid5:95, mid6:100, mid7:105, mid8:110, mid9:115, mid10:120, mid11:125, mid12:125, mid13:125, mid14:130, mid15:130, mid16:135, mid17:135, mid18:140, mid19:140, mid20:145, mid21:145, mid22:150, mid23:150, mid24:155, mid25:150, mid26:155, mid27:155, mid28:155, mid29:160, mid30:160, mid31:160},

            { row:3, rate:0.5, mid1:130, mid2:140, mid3:150, mid4:170, mid5:190, mid6:200, mid7:210, mid8:210, mid9:215, mid10:215, mid11:215, mid12:220, mid13:220, mid14:225, mid15:225, mid16:230, mid17:235, mid18:235, mid19:230, mid20:230, mid21:235, mid22:230, mid23:235, mid24:240, mid25:230, mid26:235, mid27:230, mid28:235, mid29:230, mid30:235, mid31:240},

            { row:4, rate:0.6, mid1:240, mid2:240, mid3:250, mid4:250, mid5:250, mid6:250, mid7:260, mid8:275, mid9:280, mid10:290, mid11:290, mid12:285, mid13:280, mid14:285, mid15:280, mid16:270, mid17:270, mid18:265, mid19:265, mid20:270, mid21:270, mid22:265, mid23:260, mid24:260, mid25:260, mid26:260, mid27:250, mid28:255, mid29:250, mid30:250, mid31:250},

            { row:5, rate:0.7, mid1:540, mid2:540, mid3:540, mid4:510, mid5:480, mid6:480, mid7:460, mid8:460, mid9:450, mid10:440, mid11:430, mid12:420, mid13:400, mid14:390, mid15:390, mid16:385, mid17:370, mid18:360, mid19:340, mid20:340, mid21:330, mid22:330, mid23:320, mid24:310, mid25:310, mid26:300, mid27:300, mid28:295, mid29:290, mid30:290, mid31:285 },

          { row:6, rate:1.0, mid1:560, mid2:560, mid3:560, mid4:550, mid5:530, mid6:510, mid7:490, mid8:480, mid9:470, mid10:460, mid11:450, mid12:440, mid13:440, mid14:430, mid15:420, mid16:410, mid17:400, mid18:390, mid19:390, mid20:380, mid21:380, mid22:370, mid23:370, mid24:370, mid25:360, mid26:360, mid27:350, mid28:350, mid29:350, mid30:330, mid31:330 },
        ];
/*var inival = [data[0].min, data[1].min, data[2].min, data[3].min, data[4].min, data[5].min, data[6].min];*/
        svg.selectAll("g")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("rect")
                .attr("x", 40)
                .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return d.row * 30;
                })
                .attr("height", 25)
                .attr("width", 10)
                .style("fill","blue")
                .style("margin-top",25)
                .attr("transform", "translate(30,0)");


               var ydata = [{"val":"0-9"}, {"val":"20-29"}, {"val":"40-49"}, {"val":"60-69"}, {"val":"80-89"},  {"val":"100+"}];
      //add x and y axis
               var x = d3.scale.linear()
                    .range([0, 720]);

                /*var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
                    .range([180, 0]);*/
               var y = d3.scale.ordinal()/*.domain(d3.range(ydata.length)).rangePoints([180, 0])*/                   .range([180, 0]);   
                /*y.domain().tickvalues*/


                var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(x)
                    .orient("bottom")
                    .ticks(5)
                    .tickFormat(function(d) { return d + "%"; });


                /*  d3.csv("_/age-group.csv", function(data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
        d.open = +d.open;       //  <=== Add this line in!
    });*/


    /*d3.csv("_/agegroups.csv", function(error, data) {
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.age = +d.age-groups;

    });*/


                var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(y)
                    .orient("left")
                    .ticks(6);
                    /*.tickValues(ydata.map(function(d){return d.val;}));*/

                /*yAxis.tickValues([0-9,20-29,40-49,60-69,80-89,100]);*/
                /*yAxis.tickValues(ydata.map(function(d) { return d.val; }));*/

                x.domain([0,25]);
                /*y.domain(ydata.map(function (d) {return d.val; }));   */             /*y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.age;}));*/
                /*y.domain([10,100]);*/ 
                    /*.tickFormat(function(d,i){return d.ydat[i]});*/
/*                y.domain([]);*/


                /*y.domain(yAxis);*/



                /*y.domain();*/




                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "x-axis")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(70,230)")
                    .attr("height",4)
                    .call(xAxis).append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(0)")
    .attr("y", 50)
    .attr("x",190)
    .attr("dx", "-1.5em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .style("font-size","15")
    .style("color","grey")
    .text("Percentage of World Population");

                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "y-axis")
                     .attr("transform", "translate(70,30)")
                                        .attr("width",4)

                    .call(yAxis).append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", -50)
    .attr("x",-32)
    .attr("dx", "1.5em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .style("font-size","15")
    .style("color","grey")
    .text("Age Range");

    });
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: what is your question again - are you having problems in adding range data for yaxis? In the code you shown the yaxis data is not displayed but in the link you provided it does get shown. Also explain what do you want to do when you say "decreasing the thickness of both the Y and X Axis"

Comment: @D3_GXT_Java thanks for following up on this. All my issue mentioned above are resolved. Now I want perfectly align the ticks on Y-axis corresponding to their bars. Can you please help me out in implementing it.

Comment: see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544546/d3-js-align-text-labels-between-ticks-on-the-axis/17544785#17544785 may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this link](http://plnkr.co/edit/fbgrMZXwfmuuZajOotgl?p=preview) working plnkr - i have minimized the rangePoints to [300,0]. Then the ticks will be arranged in the middle. Hope it helps.

```
 var y = d3.scale.ordinal().domain(ydata.map(function(d) {
        return d.val;
      })).rangePoints([300, 0]);
```

Comment: Can you please help me up in making this work in responsive mode as well. It would be really great if we can get this done ASAP. Thanks

Comment: what is responsive mode you mean slider and the bars ?