# Connecting two x axis through a line on histograms

Tags: d3.js

Please could someone guide me how to draw a connecting line between two x axis.  There are two histograms on the svg and I want to connect two x axis between  the data e.g. 1st record (010999) is connecting to 523,524,525,526 vs 6th record (011739) is connecting with 000200 twice or 000200 is connecting twice with 011739.

```
1. 010999   000523  
2. 010999   000524  
3. 010999   000525  
4. 010999   000526  
5. 011000   000526  
6. 011739   000200  
7. 011740   000200
```

[Image of how it should be looking][1]

Current working code is available here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/p3f2o4Zei6QWoNbIkB5Y?p=preview

but I am not sure how to go about connecting lines. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty straight-forward unless I'm misunderstanding something. I've added:

```
var connections = d3.select("#firstchart").append("g")
    .attr("class", "connections");

  connections.selectAll("path")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .style("stroke", "#FFCC66")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return "M "+x1(d.column9)+" 150 C "+x1(d.column9)+" 250,"+x2(d.column10)+" 220 , "+x2(d.column10)+" "+320;
    });
```

Here's [the result](http://plnkr.co/edit/hQpIKf5jcUDRfFgoSxpL?p=preview).

Comment: This is great! Thanks. How can change the line type to curve? like Interpolate basic and also x axis ticks not aligned to the bar (y).  Do you know how do i fix this?  Really appreciate. Thanks

Comment: I've updated the plunker to use cubic beziers (see edited answer). Hardcoding the path's `d` attribute felt like the easier approach as your data defines two points per line.

Regarding aligning ticks, this has been answered numerous times (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544546/d3-js-align-text-labels-between-ticks-on-the-axis). If you're still having trouble, post a new question.